# Change default configuration for TensorFlow Session?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is it possible to change the default Session configuration, either within Python or by setting environment variables, etc.?

Specifically I'd like

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    ...
```

to use up much less memory when I'm running small side tests in parallel to other jobs. So I'd the above to behave the same as

```
gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.1)
config = tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options)
with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
    ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't think there's a way to set process-wide default, but here's the pattern I use.

```
def create_session():
  config = tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)
  config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.3 # don't hog all vRAM
  sess = tf.InteractiveSession("", config=config)
  return sess

sess=create_session()
a=tf.constant(1)
b=tf.constant(2)
sess.run([a+b])
```

Comment: I am using a library which instantiates the session directly, and I cannot change it to use my `create_session` function. So, still no way to configure this system-wide ? I saw the discussion [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14585)